# Is there a way to change the data type of specific elements in a list based on their properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

Let's assume I have a list1 of floats, where the ones in bold are whole numbers:

```
list1 = [1.8, **4.0**, 3.2, 12.9, **18.0**, **6.0**, 7.6, **9.0**]
```

I now want to make another list2 of only integers with only the whole number floats from list1:

```
list2 = [**4, 18, 6, 9**]
```

So far, I've tried something like this:

```
list1 = [1.8, 4.0, 3.2, 12.9, 18.0, 6.0, 7.6, 9.0]
list2 = filter(lambda item: type(item) == int, list1)
print(list(list2))
```

However, the code is still reading the whole number floats as floats rather than integers.

Is there a way to selectively convert the whole number floats into integers in the list?

Comment: You can check working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
list1 = [1.8, 4.0, 3.2, 12.9, 18.0, 6.0, 7.6, 9.0]

list2 = [int(x) for x in list1 if x.is_integer()]

#[4, 18, 6, 9]
```

You can also do:

```
[int(x) for x in list1 if x%1 == 0]  #division by 1 will give 0 for integers

#[4, 18, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
list1 = [1.8, 4.0, 3.2, 12.9, 18.0, 6.0, 7.6, 9.0]
list2 = [int(num) for num in list1 if num == int(num)]
print(list2)
```

**Result:**

```
[4, 18, 6, 9]
```